# Rails 4.2 upgrade: Asset names passed to helpers should not include the "/assets/" prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I upgraded from Rails 4.1 to 4.2. I get the following error now:

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AbsoluteAssetPathError at /

Asset names passed to helpers should not include the "/assets/" prefix. Instead of "/assets/spinner.gif", use "spinner.gif"
```

The error message is clear. However, I don't know what it's talking about. It highlights this line of code:

```
  <div class="loading">
    <%= image_tag asset_path('spinner.gif') %>
  </div>
```

I do not use the literal string '/assets/' in that line of code. So what is this error referring to?

I was able to resolve that specific error by removing the call to `asset_path` and just using `image_tag 'spinner.gif'`; however, I still get the error right here (I am using Paperclip gem):

```
<%= image_tag current_user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
```

caused by this:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing-user.png')
```

Again, it is complaining about asset_path.

UPDATE:

Error only occurs when I pass asset_path to image_tag method:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing-user.png')
 => "/assets/missing-user.png" 

helper.image_tag(ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing-user.png'))
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AbsoluteAssetPathError: Asset names passed to helpers should not include the "/assets/" prefix. Instead of "/assets/missing-user.png", use "missing-user.png"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) will pass the source option to `asset_path` on its own:

```
image_tag("icon")
# => <img alt="Icon" src="/assets/icon" />
image_tag("icon.png")
# => <img alt="Icon" src="/assets/icon.png" />
image_tag("/icons/icon.gif", height: '32', width: '32')
# => <img alt="Icon" height="32" src="/icons/icon.gif" width="32" />
```

So when you call `image_tag asset_path('spinner.gif')` you're actually doing `image_tag( '/assets/spinner.gif' )` which is why you get the sprockets warning.

Comment: This is new in Rails 4.2? It was not an issue in 4.1.

Comment: No, idea. It could be that the warning was introduced in 4.2. I would'nt get hung up on that though. Just fix it and move on to more important things.